# How do you view CD Keys in Steam?

Tags: steam

How do I view a CD key on the latest version of Steam? Valve reworked the layout and there is no CD key option on the right side of the Steam Library.

Answer (score 5):

On the library screen:

- Right-click the game name on the left side
- Click Manage
- Click CD Keys

[image: Steam CD Keys menu]

Comment: Although not all games bought on steam have CD Keys associated with them

Comment: Since this question was marked as a duplicate, I moved this answer over to the other question.